# Узнать о подгрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Пишу расширение для google chrome, на страницах vk он выполняет некие действия, например перекрашивает заголовки постов в сообществах в другой цвет. Скрипт работает и всё хорошо, но если я прокручу страницу ниже, она подгрузит новые посты, которые уже будут без изменений, т.к. скрипт отработал. Есть ли какая-то возможность отследить изменение в DOM, чтобы можно было запустить скрипт заново?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел сам, если кому интересно -

```
$("body").on("DOMNodeInserted", function () { 
    // код
 });
```